# Reassign value of Exception.Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a task to make a universal solution that would display only an error text in a modal popup if a user does not have specific rights otherwise, it should show the whole text with an error id etc. The question is can I somehow re-assign value to Exception.Message?

I've done everything else, I need just that. The problem is that the Exception.The message is a getter and has no setter component.

I have something like this:

```
var err = new Excetion(some parameters);
var message = string.Empty;
if (User.isInRole("somerole"))
    message = err.Message;
else message = err.Note;
showError(message, and some other parameters);
```

Is there any other way, because all showError functions are called with `showError(err.Message, and some parameters)`so that I wouldn't re-write all these calls? Just replace err.Message.

Hope I wasn't too wage. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap that exception in another

```
var myException = new Exception ("my own message", err);
```

then you still have the original within the `InnerException` and can access it like

```
myException.InnerException
```

Comment: Would it mean that I still have to re-write all function calls for showError method?